# Having trouble transcribing mySQL query in peewee

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, peewee

I have a query in mySQL that produces desired output when entered into the mySQL terminal, however, I'm having trouble trying to write the same query in the Peewee ORM.

Here is the mySQL query:

```
select t.PATH, s.PATH from media_data as t 
left outer join media_data as s on 
s.SHOW = t.SHOW and s.EPISODE = t.EPISODE and s.SHOT = t.SHOT and s.FRAME = t.FRAME and t.LABEL_TYPE = 'target' 
where s.LABEL_TYPE = 'source' and s.SHOW = 'doc_d' and s.EPISODE = '102'        
union 
select t.PATH, s.PATH from media_data as t 
right outer join media_data as s on
s.SHOW = t.SHOW and s.EPISODE = t.EPISODE and s.SHOT = t.SHOT and s.FRAME = t.FRAME and t.LABEL_TYPE = 'target' 
where s.LABEL_TYPE = 'source' and s.SHOW = 'doc_d' and s.EPISODE = '102';
```

And here is my attempt at the corresponding peewee query

```
s = media_data.alias()
t = media_data.alias()

predicate = (s.SHOW == t.SHOW and s.EPISODE == t.EPISODE and s.SHOT == t.SHOT 
             and s.FRAME == t.FRAME and t.LABEL_TYPE == 'target')

query = media_data.select(s.PATH, t.PATH).join(t, join_type=JOIN.FULL_OUTER, on=predicate).where(s.LABEL_TYPE == 'source' and s.SHOW == show and s.EPISODE == episode)
```

When I try to run python, it tells me there's a problem with 'JOIN.FULL_OUTER' even though it is used exactly as defined in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues. First you need to use `&` instead of `and` in your predicates and to use parentheses to properly bind these:

```
predicate = ((S.show == T.show) &
             (S.episode == T.episode) &
             (S.shot == T.shot) &
             (S.frame == T.frame) &
             (T.label_type == 'target'))
```

Additionally, if your database is complaining about full outer join, perhaps it does not support this type of JOIN (and hence the reason for the awkward UNION query)?

If you have confirmed that your database *does* support full outer join, then the following should work:

```
T = MediaData.alias()

predicate = ((MediaData.show == T.show) &
             (MediaData.episode == T.episode) &
             (MediaData.shot == T.shot) &
             (MediaData.frame == T.frame) &
             (T.label_type == 'target'))

query = (MediaData
         .select(MediaData.path, T.path)
         .join(T, join_type=JOIN.FULL_OUTER, on=predicate)
         .where(
             (MediaData.label_type == 'source') &
             (MediaData.show == 'doc_d') &
             (MediaData.episode == '102')))
```

Query:

```
SELECT "t1"."path", "t2"."path"
FROM "mediadata" AS "t1"
FULL OUTER JOIN "mediadata" AS "t2" ON (
 ("t2"."show" = "t1"."show") AND 
 ("t2"."episode" = "t1"."episode") AND
 ("t2"."shot" = "t1"."shot") AND
 ("t2"."frame" = "t1"."frame") AND
 ("t2"."label_type" = 'target'))
WHERE (
 ("t1"."label_type" = 'source') AND 
 ("t1"."show" = 'doc_d')) AND
 ("t1"."episode" = '102'))
```